# Python Pandas Pivot Table - counting points

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe, iterator

I have an issue with Pivot table in Python. Let's say that I have below values in list:

team_A_id = [1,5,10]

team_A_result = 0

and below data frame:

```
id             points
3                36
4                0
5                11
7                6
10               23
```

How could I using (perhaps) "for loop" find by team A id in list points and count them. Output should be:

result_team_A = 34

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `isin`  and `sum`

```
team_A_id = [1,5,10]
df.loc[df.id.isin(team_A_id),'points'].sum()
Out[136]: 34
```

Comment: but I can see error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: @Tmiskiewicz then Id is in your index `df.loc[df.index.isin(team_A_id),'points'].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

this will return the rows for the team A:

```
df.iloc[team_A_id]
```

result team A can be obtained by:

```
df['points].sum()
```

TLDR:

```
df.iloc[team_A_id]['points].sum()
```